# Difference between Oracle refresh group and a simple transaction

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

Question about Oracle materialized views and refresh groups defined in a single node -- not used for replication.

Assuming that I refresh of a set of materialized views on demand in my own code, is there any functional difference between using a refresh group to update these views in a transactionally consistent manner, or skipping MV groups and simply updating all the related MVs in a single transaction?

My testing indicates that the MV group refresh is slower, not sure why.  Could it be dbms_job overhead?

Comment: Are you sure that the manual refresh is being done atomically?  If the refresh group is meaningfully slower, my suspicion is that you are actually doing a non-atomic refresh (truncate and direct-path insert) when you refresh individual materialized views while the refresh group is doing an atomic refresh (delete and conventional-path insert).  Not knowing your Oracle version or how you're calling `dbms_view.refresh`, it's hard to say for sure but you wouldn't be the first person to make that mistake.

Comment: Using 11g (11.2.0.3) and you are right, I was confused about atomic vs non-atomic refresh.   Thx.